# XPS 15: Black screen with blinking cursor after update

Tags: boot, 20.04, login-screen, xps

I have installed `Ubuntu` `20.04.1` along with Windows 10 on XPS15 9500 and everything worked fine until Ubuntu asked me to do some updates. I clicked ok and after the updates finished I rebooted the system and landed on a **black screen with a blinking cursor**.

What works is: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> so that I land on tty4, then I can click: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> OR <kbd>→</kbd> which brings me from tty2 to tty6, if I click further I land either on tty1 or tty7 (where the login GUI is, which I have expected to be there by default).

So I would like to know how to land on the Login GUI by default without the black screen at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line with the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and add `nomodeset` to the variables, so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Then update-grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Note: This solution disables your graphics card until you remove `nomodeset`. The problem was probably a graphics driver problem, so you should find a more long-term solution. Try going to the command line again and entering `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and removing `nomodeset` from the grub.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done selected correct settings while making live making live usb because I also faced same issue while installing Ubuntu It was working fine but after rebooting it disspeared and the grub screen was not present so I refer rufus software while making a live usb and selecting GPT or MBR partitioning scheme according to your laptop.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu with a Rufus made USB stick and the initial installation went well, Ubuntu and Windows could be started. Then Ubuntu asked to make some updates, and after this I get the black screen when selecting Ubuntu in the boot process

Comment: You are right, I have installed NVIDIA drivers and now it works, so I removed nomodeset again.